# My nginx returns 404? I'm not sure why

Tags: apt, server, nginx, webserver

My nginx returns 404? I'm not sure why

Here is my /sites-available/default file, nginx.conf is default I haven't changed anything.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

    location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific and provide more details. What would you like to serve with nginx? A specific app or just an example php file? Did you create a symlink for you vhost config file from /sites-available/ to /sites-enabled/? Did you restart nginx after config file changes? What does your nginx log files say? Is there an index.php file in your document root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/public? Is server name 'example.com' just obfuscated or do you maybe need to enter your own domain here? Is php7.0-fpm installed? Why to you have a second 'try_files' in the location ~ \.php$ ?